# does anyone know how to remove these warnings?

Tags: reactjs

**index.js:1 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code.**

- Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
- If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps.
  Please update the following components: FirestoreConnectWrapped(Details)

**This is my code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {firestoreConnect} from 'react-redux-firebase';
import {compose} from 'redux';

const Details =(props)=>{
   const {project} =props;
   if(project){
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <br/>
        <Card>
  <Card.Body>
  <Card.Title>{project.Title}</Card.Title>
    <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">

      <p>
      {project.content}
      </p>
    </blockquote>

  <Card.Text>
        <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
</Card>
</div>
    )
   }
   else{
     return (
       <div className="container">
         Loading project......
       </div>
     )
   }
}

const mapStateToProps =(state,ownProps)=>{
  const id=ownProps.match.params.id;
  const projects =state.firestore.data.projects;
  const project =projects ? projects\[id\] :null 
  return {
    project :project 
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),

  firestoreConnect(props=>\[
    {collection:'projects',doc:props.match.params.id}
  \])
)(Details)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can take it out of strict mode

change this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <App />
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

or do what the warning says and fix it? either by using the new recommended way or not using that function at all

Comment: Do you know how to fix the warning ?? Instead of taking out the StrictMode

Comment: either you use `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` somewhere in your code or a package you use uses it so let me know which it is